# AWS SDK PHP: DownloadSyncBuilder not Concurrent?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, concurrency

Currently I am downloading information from an S3 bucket to my local drive.  I am using DownloadSyncBuilder due to the regex filter functionality.  However, when I monitor my file count, I realize that while it does download 200 (my concurrency) at a time, it still takes a long time (8-10 s) to download the next batch.  Note that my files are tiny (<1kb) but there's just a lot of them.

My code:

```
$dsb = DownloadSyncBuilder::getInstance();
$dsb->setClient($dynamodbclient);
$dsb->setDirectory("mydir");
$dsb->setBucket(BUCKET_NAME);
$dsb->setKeyPrefix($prefix);
$dsb->setConcurrency(200);
$dsb->addRegexFilter("some cool regex filter dude");
$dsb->build()->transfer();
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried using different concurrency values (e.g., 1, 20, 50, 100) and compared the performance? 200 might not be ideal value for your system and the files.

Comment: Yes, anything too high (eg. >600) may crash the script and even when at 1000, it is still taking approximately 1-2 minutes to move on to the next set of 1000 files.

Comment: I was thinking that fewer than 200 might be better.

Comment: Didn't catch the low values on the first readthrough, my mistake.  I'll give that a try